# Queue manager with decent PHP client

Tags: php, queue, activemq-classic, jobs, beanstalkd

First of all, this is not a "what's the best queue manager..." sort of question.

I currently use Gearman for queue management. It's fast, it's reliable, but I do miss some features and I would like to understand better options according to my needs. I use to work with Delayed_job and Resque in Ruby, but even with those I didn't found all the requirements below:

1. I don't need a blazing fast server (we deal with ~ 3k tasks/jobs per day)
2. I need it to be able to reenqueue a task
3. Store current tasks in a persistent way (not memory only)

   - It should be able to replicate data among servers (in order to maintain High Availability in case of server crash)
4. List item

   - And to be able to have a timeout that will, automatically reenqueue
5. Be able to delay a task

   - schedule to 5 minutes from now
   - or schedule to next Sunday
6. Be able to manage the Queue

   - How many jobs per queue?
   - What are the jobs about?
   - Can I query the Queue?

Other thoughts:

- Being able to monitor the server status through Zabbix would be nice.

I had a great first impression about [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/). I do miss, only, data replication among servers. I also had a nice impression regarding [ActiveMQ Apollo](http://activemq.apache.org/apollo/), but I didn't see how to schedule with delay.

Any thoughts?

Comment: We use RabbitMQ for this purpose with this plugin: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/ which allows you to queue messages with a `x-delay` value in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Beanstalkd does most of that - and you can save the binary log. It's just local though. monitoring is easy, just connect, sends a 'STATS' call, and read the results, optionally going back to get a count from known tubes as well.

There are two other potential - remotely hosted - solutions that have high availability claims. Amazon SQS, and [IronMQ](http://www.iron.io/mq). One advantage of Iron (though I've not personally used it) is that it also has an almost 100% Beanstalkd-compatible interface, just more 'enterprise' for the backend.

Comment: Thanks Alister. For now, I bet in Beanstalkd. But I do miss sync among servers. Let me check IronMQ to see how it handle data replication and I let you know.

Comment: Hi Alister, as I could see IronMQ is pretty nice but it just work as a service. That for us is an issue. I would use Amazon SQS if I could use it in the cloud right now.